# Why am I seeing deleted questions?

Tags: support

I can't post a screenshot right now, but when I look at my **Votes Cast** list, I can see questions which I have voted to close, with **closure (deleted)** as the status, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20492520/969613).

However I can view the questions just fine. Could this be a bug?

Comment: That question is not deleted that you link to.

Comment: But it says it is in the Votes Cast list.

Comment: The close **vote** is deleted

Answer (score 3):

No, this is not a bug, When you see a **closure (deleted)** on your votes cast list. It means your close vote on the question has been deleted not the question itself.

Comment: Aah that makes a lot of sense, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Close votes expire if no new votes are cast after a given amount of time(or for other reasons such as question closure) and the system then marks them as **Closure (deleted)**.

It's the vote that's deleted. The question you linked to is itself not deleted.

Comment: If the question gets closed then the vote gets deleted too